# BackgroundWorker: Does every method called from the DoWorkEventHandler run in the background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, backgroundworker

I have a MVVM application which loads data via a XML on a server. The XML is downloaded with `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync()` and then is parsed by a method. The problem is that the XML is kind of big so the UI freezes for a while (2-3 seconds or so), while the XML is parsing.

My idea to solve this problem was to use a BackgroundWorker to handle the parsing. But does every method called from my `DoWorkEventHandle`r run in the background thread? Even the webclients event handlers?

The whole parsing thing takes place in a `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` so it would be kind of useless if that didn't run in a background thread.

Thanks for you help, Stack Overflow has been amazing so far :) Keep it up!

Comment: Trivially solve your problem by no longer using the *Async* version of the method.  There's no need, it already runs in a worker thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful when using Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP) components from a `BackgroundWorker`. In particular, if they are created and started by the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` method, then they will raise their events on `ThreadPool` threads rather than the UI thread. An [MSDN article published yesterday](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) has an illustration of this situation and an explanation of why this happens.

If you call `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` from `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` (which is running on a `ThreadPool` thread), then `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` will run on a `ThreadPool` thread. However, this may be a *different* thread than the `BackgroundWorker` thread; and the `BackgroundWorker` *may* have completed already by the time that `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` starts.

So, I wouldn't say that it runs "within" the `BackgroundWorker`. Rather, it's acting in a free-threaded style. The event will fire on a `ThreadPool` thread which may or may not be the same as the `BackgroundWorker` thread, and the `BackgroundWorker` may or may not be complete when the event fires.

I think a better solution may be to keep the `WebClient` owned by the UI thread, and have its event handler kick off a `BackgroundWorker`. That way, both EAP components are owned by the UI thread and will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as I understood, DoWorkEventHandler fires in a separate thread. Also check out ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem etc which might be a simpler process for you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it all runs in the bgworker. But you have to be carefull. If you update properties which are bound to the view and you update them in your bgworker (and of course NotifyPropertyChanged is raised) there will be an exception! (Cause you want to get data from another thread in your UI Thread).

Comment: How do i solve this problem then? Do all parsing and only update the UI when the thread is completed?

Comment: Hi Richard, just saw your comment. I would have posted an example, but as far as I can see you got your answer ;)